# How capture Sql_infomessage from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Have an Windows Forms application that captures sql_informessage event that update a progress bar.
How can I do the same on  on ASP.NET application,

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Matt Berseth's AJAX Progress Bar control](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/05/aspnet_ajax_progress_bar_contr.html)?  This is a pretty close representation of what can be done in ASP.NET Webforms in comparison to Win Form apps.